# How to use custom post types for repeated content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create an HTML table in which every time the admin adds a new post to a certain custom post type it will use the custom fields from the custom post just created to create a new row with the values on the table (one of the custom fields is category which decides in which table it will appear)

```
    add_action('save_post', 'check_for_post_in_database');

 $categories = array("1", "2", "3");

function addTableRow($fieldCategory,$fieldName,$fieldSubject){
    $tr = $dom->createElement('tr');
    getElementById($field)->appendChild($tr);
    
    $td = $dom->createElement('td', $fieldName);
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    
    $td = $dom->createElement('td', 'Value');
    $tr->appendChild($td);

    $td = $dom->createElement('td', $fieldSubject);
    $tr->appendChild($td);
    
    $table->appendChild($domAttribute);
    $dom->appendChild($table);
}




function check_for_post_in_database($post_id) {
if( get_post( $post_id ) == null ) {

$fieldCategory = get_field( "category" );
$fieldName = get_field( "name" );
$fieldSubject = get_field( "subject" );

foreach ($categories as $value) {
      if( $value = $fieldCategory) {
        add_row($fieldCategory,$fieldName,$fieldSubject);
} 
}
$categories = array("1", "2", "3");

$field = get_field( "category" );

foreach ($categories as $value) {
      if( $value = $field) {

} else {
 return;
}
}
```

This is the html code:

```
<div class="naccs">
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="gc gc--1-of-3">
            <div class="menu">
                <div class="active">
                    <span class="light"></span>
                    <span>1</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="light"></span>
                    <span>2</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="light"></span>
                    <span>3</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gc gc--2-of-3">
            <ul class="nacc">
                <li class="active">
                    <div>
                        <div class="tbl-header">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>example</th>
                                        <th>example</th>
                                        <th>group</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tbl-content">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class = "table-row">
                                        <td>250</td>
                                        <td>example</td>
                                        <td>group</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                    <div class="tbl-content">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="2">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class = "table-row">
                                        <td>250</td>
                                        <td>example</td>
                                        <td>group</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div>
                    <div class="tbl-content">
                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="3">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class = "table-row">
                                        <td>250</td>
                                        <td>דוגמא</td>
                                        <td>קבוצה</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your existing code?

Comment: wish I had the code I just tried a few times and understood that nothing I'm doing is working so I came here for answers

Comment: You won't get answers unless you show your code. It's kind of the rules here.